# Is it more efficient to request value or to just automatically set it

Tags: javascript, coding-style, computation-theory

So I am writing code in javascript that I am trying to make the code as efficient as possible because it will be running through a but load of data. My questions which is more efficient:

1.

```
foreach MyObjects{
    if(MyObject.getBoolean() == false){
        MyObject.setBoolean(true);
    }
}
```

2.

```
foreach MyObjects{
    MyObject.setBoolean(true);
}
```

I know my foreach is not real but I am asking which is better when running the statement many thousands of times?

Comment: The latter - avoiding the if statement, and a comparision must be quicker

Comment: @suspectus He is asking if it would be quicker to have the if statement if for example, 90% of the booleans were already true. (you comment may still be correct, but you don't specifically address the question, so I am hoping for some clarification.)

Comment: It depends on what `getBoolean` and `setBoolean` are doing. If `setBoolean` is expensive, it might be quicker to avoid unnecessary calls to it.

Comment: Testing 200 items with the first 100 set true and the second 100 set to false. Your second method is roughly twice as fast. [Here is the test](http://jsperf.com/check-first-or-just-set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why you would think that the first might be okay because there is a 'filtering' element. But the iterator still has to iterate over all the values whether they are `false` or not, so just explicitly telling them to be `true` wields the same results but with one less function call.

So the latter.

**Edit**:

As Ken suggests, it depends how expensive the different `setBoolean` and `getBoolean` methods are. If `setBoolean` does more than just set a value to `true`, then the first could possibly  be quicker. But it's hard to imagine they do anything other than what their method names suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I coud be wrong, but it seems like the second option required less steps:

```
foreach MyObjects{
    MyObject.setBoolean(true);
}
```

In the first option you are checking the Boolean for each and every value and then for those that are false, you are setting to true. (1 operation guaranteed (get), with the possibility of second (set)). In the second method you are also finding every object, but skipping the check and simply setting (1 operation only). Therefore, although there probably isn't a significant difference in the runtime, **the second one is more efficient.**